# Scala - Sort efficiently to only get top 10 values

Tags: scala, performance, sorting

I have a large Map of customer and say their budget:

```
val myMap = Map("Leo" -> 100.24, "Tea" -> 210.01, "Bob" -> 1.03, ... with 500+ more elements)
val myCustomers = List("Leo", "Tea", "Bob", ... with 500+ more)
```

Currently, I am sorting all elements in the map by value and then I take the top 10 customers with the highest budgets.

```
val sorted = myCustomers.sortWith((c1, c2) => myMap(c1) > myMap(c2))
println("Top 10 highest earners are:")
println(sorted.take(10))
```

I do not feel this is efficient enough. Is there a way this can be improved?

Comment: _"I do not feel this is efficient enough"_ why? Did you already benchmarked and found this to be a bottleneck? or you just want a premature optimization?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have not benchmarked it but I was wondering if there can be ways to improve it in terms of efficiency.

Comment: You can not talk about efficiency without benchmarking first, any kind of change you do could either improve or worse the performance of the function. If it isn't a bottle neck do not bother about it, strive for code that is easier to maintain not more efficient just because. And I doubt anything would be easier to maintain that `sort.take`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to sort at all, to get the top 10 customers. You can do that in O(n) steps with O(1) space without sorting. But if this is a query you need often, then a map is simply the wrong datastructure.